# HTML 5 Animated Symbols

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make animated symbols which show how the symbol should be drawn.  Something similar to this:

http://www.handwritingforkids.com/handwrite/cursive/animation/images/animation_a.gif

How I would go about doing this in HTML5?

Comment: ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 `<canvas>` element is what you want.  The canvas is a drawable context where you can create arbitrary shapes.

MDN has a tutorial for getting started with the canvas API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial

Answer (score 0):

In pure HTML (even 5) you can't do this (note: <canvas> also requires JavaScript). Maybe, just maybe you could hack it together in HTML+CSS, but it is much easier to do it in JavaScript.

I suggest the [RaphaëlJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) vector graphics library